# Histórico de transações, como é implementado?

Tags: php, pdo

Preciso fazer um histórico da(s) última(s) compra(s) do usuário (essas infos serão mostrados em uma `table`).

Poderiam me dar dicas de como normalmente é salvo esse histórico? (não precisa fazer para mim)

Normalmente cria-se uma coluna e dentro dela é salvo um array com números de `id`'s dos produtos ou salva-se todos os `id`'s separados por vírgulas? poderiam me dar dicas de implementar esta parte?

será mostrado a `quantidade`, `id_produto`, `valor unitario do produro`

Comment: seria interessante ter alguma tentativa sua, para que alguem lhe ajude. senao fica parecente tipo faça por mim entende

Comment: Nenhum nem outro. Poderia dar mais detalhes do que deseja fazer log

Comment: fiz a atualização, não sei se ficou claro

Comment: Geralmente, se guarda um id por linha, na verdade depende do banco de dados que irá utilizar

Comment: Melhorou, se possível adicione as estruturas das tabelas relacionadas a esse processo. Além do produto quais informações vão? quantidade? endereço de entrega? etc

Answer (score 0):

A ideia básica de criar um histórico é ter uma 'desnormalização controlado' no seu banco de dados. Em outras palavras, você precisa de uma nova tabela onde os campos sejam as descrições dos 'objetos' manipulados, alguns ids podem ser importantes também.

Exemplo:

Uma tabela de histórico com os campos `id`, `id_venda`, `endereco_entrega`. O cliente faz um compra e durante o processamento muda o endereço de entrega do seu cadastro, agora imagine o que aconteceria se tabela de histórico tivesse o id do endereço no lugar de sua descrição? Loja poderia despachar o produto para um endereço errado já que o cliente pode mudar essa informação quando quiser.

O certo é gravar seus 'valores descritivos' para registrar aquela exata compra naquele instante, algo como tirar uma foto para compara-la com outra.

Comment: http://blog.vanderli.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Foreign-keys.jpg seria algo deste tipo? fazer uma foreign key com uma outra tabela? seguinte o exemplo da imagem, o ID (Tabela Customers, provavelmente esta é auto incremental) estará fazendo referência ao CUST_ID (Tabela Orders) (está aqui não será auto incrementada e não deverá ser primary key, correto?)